# Составить запрос чтобы записи с определённым условием попали в выборку с TOP N rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица:

```
services (id (unique), service_id, user_name, name)
```

У меня есть запрос, который выбирает 10 строк по определенному `user`.

```
select * from services where user_name = 'dev' and rownum <= 10
```

мне необходимо изменить запрос так, чтобы если у данного пользователя есть запись в таблице с service_id = 15, то эта запись попадала в выборку.

В MySql у меня получалось это сделать с помощью `Order by + limit`, но как это сделать в Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select 
    id, service_id, user_name 
from services 
where user_name = 'dev'
order by case service_id when 15 then 1 end nulls last
fetch first 10 rows only
;
```

Для релизов БД до 12c, где выраженние [*row limiting*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) было ещё недоступно, преобразуйте в подзапрос:

```
select * from (<запрос без row limiting>) where rownum <= 10
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня БД 12с, и интересует такой вопрос, если у меня в таблице миллионы записей (даже с условием where user_name = 'dev'), то работает быстро когда я пишу and rownum <= 10. А если я буду использовать fetch first, то мне кажется это будет дольше. Сперва выберутся все миллионы записей, отсортируются и только затем вернутся первые десять. Или я неправильно рассуждаю?

Comment: `fetch first` с сортировкой ничего общего не имеет. Вы попробуйте, если будет сильно тормозить, то можно подумать, как с индексами помочь  или может даже без сортировки обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id, 
       service_id, 
       user, 
       name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user 
                          ORDER BY CASE WHEN service_id = 15
                                        THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                   END, id /* DESC */ ) rn
FROM services -- Спасибо товарищу 0xdb
/* WHERE user = 'some_user' */
)
SELECT id, service_id, user, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY user, id /* DESC */ ;
```

Comment: в первом select нужно еще добавить from services WHERE user = 'some_user' ?

Comment: @Александр не нужно, а можно. Если хотите получить записи для одного пользователя. Или установить иное условие. если нужны записи для некоей группы пользователей. Ну то есть всё зависит от текущей хотелки.

Comment: @0xdb *если в запросе нет таблицы* ??? где нет таблицы? какой таблицы? это вообще о чём?

Comment: Ух ё... точно! ща поправим...

Answer (score 0):

Постановка задачи не ясна.
Условие: `необходимо изменить запрос так, чтобы если у данного пользователя есть запись в таблице с service_id = 15, то эта запись попадала в выборку`

Добавьте ограничение к условию отбора **and service_id = 15**

В случае, если Вам необходимы пользователи, у которых есть запись с service_id равным 15 :

```
select * 
  from services s
 where s.user = 'dev' -- конкретный пользователь
   and rownum <= 10  -- результирующее количество строк
   and s.user in
     (select c.user from services c where c.service_id = 15) /* все пользователи, у которых service_id = 15
```

Comment: Оконные функции тяжелее вложенных запросов. Они также менее читабельны

Comment: нет, немного не так, нужно выбрать из таблицы ограниченное кол-во записей (например только 10 строк), но так, чтобы в них оказалась определённая запись (service_id = 15), если она у этого пользователя есть.